# Daily Activity Stream

Tags: feature-request

Every 5 days in which you are online and you gain at least 1 rep each day your bonus increases 5%. If you are not active it resets. Since there are no decimal rep it is rounded to the nearest whole number with rounding up. This way people who are gaining rep will gain more rep and those who are not active just don't receive any benefit. The rep bonus is capped at 200%

Comment: Stack Overflow has many problems. Participation *is not one of them*. Or at least, not participation that would be encouraged by this feature.

Comment: This should be [edit]ed to explain _why_ your proposal would be a good idea. It should also be made clearer what the proposal is. I have no idea what _"Also activity is getting the same amount of rep or more than your bonus."_ is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 12):

I think that encouraging activity for the sake of activity is a really good way to ensure continued additions of substandard quality questions and answers to this site.

It's also something that appears extremely easy to automate

- find random post
- add generic comment (a thankyou comment maybe, it'll just get autovacuumed anyway)
- free 200 rep every day

So I disagree with this idea.

Comment: I updated this post so that activity gets harder and harder overtime.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the value of this feature. All it appears to do is punish new users who haven't got the ball rolling. In fact, this might even *discourage* helpful participation because they know they've reached todays quota. Plus it's going to have people freaking out because they need 2 more points otherwise they're going to lose their double points bonanza. So even with your new changes, it's still a solid no from me.

Comment: @JakeFreeman what does it mean that activity gets harder and harder over time? I am thinking of making a bot that would log into my account every day and favorite / unfavorite some question to automatically simulate activity, do I need to program that bot to increase number of favorited questions as time goes by

Comment: @gnat No it is a boost your rep so if you receive rep it is increased it gets harder in you need more activity such as commenting to increase your boost.

Comment: so, in order to increase rep my bot would have to post comments instead of favoriting, right? (and automatically delete these after a while to prevent folks complaining) Good to know that

Comment: @Jake just a question:  what are you trying to fix  make better here? It just feels a pointless change to the system, with no real benefit...

Comment: Due to the overwhelming dislike for this post I will delete it.

Comment: It's not that I dislike the post - I just disagree with the idea. Nothing wrong with coming up with ideas and sharing them...

Comment: @Jake you shouldn't, honestly. It's downvoted because people disagree it's a useful feature. Not because it's a bad question. Negative score on meta has no influence over anything, so it's not bad to keep it around. Also, this way someone with a similar feature idea can find your post and see what the community thinks before posting :)